# Reference Lemma from the same document

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, theorems, cleveref

I am writing a document, where I have 3-4 Theorems, and a Lemma. I want to refer to the Lemma in the Theorems (possibly highlighted and a link to the Lemma). How should I go about doing it? I tried inserting a `\label{lma1}` in the Lemma, and then using `~\cref{lma1}`, but this refers to the Lemma as "Theorem 2.5" (the numbering is right, but I want it to display "Lemma 2.5". How do I change this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on the theorem package you're using (or if you're doing it *without* a package), you need to define a separate `lemma` environment. The following minimal working example uses [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) to define a `theorem` and `lemma` environment. [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) has been formatted to print `Lemma` for a `lemma` reference, while dummy text is provided by [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{cleveref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm}\lipsum[1]\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}See~\cref{lma1}.\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}\label{lma1}\lipsum[2]\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```